# Unable to pull all dropdown values from ui to excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

Below is the code to pull selected value of dropdown into excel. but i want to pull all values of that dropdown. Help me out please and thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub lucky()

Set winShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShellWindows = winShell.Windows
Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
For Each ie1 In winShell.Windows

  If Left(ie1.locationURL, 66) = "https://lraca-qa.wellsfargo.com/LegalAnalysis/ChangeAlertAdd.aspx" Then
        Set IE = ie1
       Exit For
   End If
Next

Dim TypeOfChange
Set TypeOfChange = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_Main_wfcGeneralInfoEdit_fbxGeneralInfo_ddlTypeOfChange")
Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = TypeOfChange.Item(TypeOfChange.selectedIndex).innerText


MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  `TypeOfChange.Options.Length` will give you the number of items in the list, and `TypeOfChange.Options(i).Text` will give the the text for the i'th option.

Comment: x = TypeOfChange.Options.Length
    For i = 1 To x
    Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value = TypeOfChange.Options(i).Text
    Next

Comment: @Tim : i am getting 'Runtime error:91, Object variable or with block variable not set' error message. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim x As Long

x = TypeOfChange.Options.Length

'Options is zero-based, so need to count from 0 to x-1
For i = 0 to x-1
    Sheet1.Cells(i+1, "A").Value = TypeOfChange.Options(i).Text
    'if you need the value for the option...
    Sheet1.Cells(i+1, "B").Value = TypeOfChange.Options(i).Value
Next
```